# Consumer not updating with notifyListeners()

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I have created a simple Widget Tree of my app in flutter that adresses the issue.

The issue is that when I call the method in my `SleepSessionData` which is a `ChangeNotifier` class, the consumer does not get fired.

There is no issue if the method containing `notifyListeners()` is called within the same widget, but when it is two sibling widgets the consumer does not update unless a `setState` is called.

[image: Widget Tree]

And a image of the screen for reference

[image]

**SleepSessionData extends ChangeNotifier**

```
void updateSelectedPlaylists(List<String> selectedPlaylists) {
    this.selectedPlaylists = selectedPlaylists;
    notifyListeners();
    _saveData();
}
```

**PlaylistSelectorWidget**

```
void selectedIndex(int index) {
    ...
    context.read<SleepSessionData>().updateSelectedPlaylists(_selectedPlaylistIds);
    setState(() {});
}
```

In my `SettingsWidget` I tried using both `Consumer` Widget and and `watch()` method. But it is as the `notifyListeners()` does not trigger the consumer/watcher. If i run a `setState()` (triggered by user input) the value from the the `ChangeNotifier` updates.

Here's my `MultiProvider` in `main.dart`

```
child: MultiProvider(
  providers: [
    ChangeNotifierProvider<MySleepData>(create: (_) => MySleepData()),
    ChangeNotifierProvider<DirectoryData>(create: (_) => DirectoryData()),
    FutureProvider<UserData>(
        create: (_) => LocalPersistence.getUserData(),
        initialData: UserData()),
    FutureProvider<SleepSessionData>(
      create: (_) => LocalPersistence.getSleepSessionData(),
      initialData: SleepSessionData(),
    )
  ],
```

Comment: I would assume it is because you are using the `FutureProvider` for your `SleepSessionData` and not the `ChangeNotifierProvider`. The documentation for `FutureProvider` says: "Takes a Future and updates dependents when the future completes." - so it only updates when the future updates but not the model / class itself. I suggest to use a `ChangeNotifierProvider` there as well and evaluate your async `getSleepSessionData` function before that

Comment: @kounex Thanks for your reply! But I don't think that's the issue. The provider and `notifyListeners()` works fine if it's `read()` and `watch()` is called from within the same widget. But in this case it doesn't. But I will test it out just to be sure!

Comment: did you try to use `listen:false`?

Comment: Thanks for posting, in my case I forgot to add     notifyListeners()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't wrap your `ChangeNotifier` inside the `FutureProvider` in order to make it works properly.

When you wrap the `ChangeNotifier` inside the `FutureProvider` it breaks the process of adding listeners to the `ChangeNotifiers` somehow. You always get 0 listeners when wrapping `ChangeNotifier` with `FutureProvider`. (You can verify this by debugging and check the `listeners` property of your `ChangeNotifier` instance.) That's why when calling `notifyListeners()`, the widgets don't rerender since they're not the listener of your `ChangeNotifier` instance.

**So the solution to your problem would be:**

- Use `ChangeNotifier` in `main.dart`

```
child: MultiProvider(
  providers: [
    ChangeNotifierProvider<MySleepData>(create: (_) => MySleepData()),
    ChangeNotifierProvider<DirectoryData>(create: (_) => DirectoryData()),
    ChangeNotifierProvider<UserData>(create: (_) => UserData()),
    ChangeNotifierProvider<SleepSessionData>(create: (_) => SleepSessionData()),
  ],
```

- In the `SessionSetupPage`, you get the data from your local store and load the changes to `SleepSessionData`

```
loadData(SleepSessionData sessionData) async {
    final data = await LocalPersistence.getData();
    sessionData.setData(data);
}

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   loadData(context.read<SleepSessionData>());
   // ..
}
```

- Then the code in your `PlaylistSelector` and `SettingsWidget` should work whenever `notifyListeners()` is called since the listeners are bound correctly now.

---

> so when the future completes it will overwrite this value

This is not totally the root cause of the issue though. Even if we create the `SleepSessionData` instance beforehand and return the same instance inside the `FutureProvider`, the problem still persists.

Answer (score 0):

You only have a `FutureProvider` that holds the `SleepSessionData` so that will only update once when the future completes.
If you want the ui to update on changes of the result of the future then you need to listen to those changes, for instance by using a `ChangeNotifierProvider`.

Additionally you are giving the `FutureProvider` an initial data with a new instance of your `SleepSessionData` so when the future completes it will overwrite this value meaning that any actions you do on the initial value will be discarded.

So a better way of doing this would be to not use a `FutureProvider` but use a `ChangeNotifierProvider` and start the future to load the data within your `SleepSessionData` class.